# What would this regex match?

Tags: php, regex

Hi any idea what this is matching
thanks

```
preg_match('/^[1-8](0|5)$/', $myValue)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Start of string
- A digit between 1 and 8
- Either a digit 0 or 5
- End of string

Answer (score 4):

Beginning of string, digit from 1-8, capturing group matching either 0 or 5, end of string.

Comment: Conclusion: waste of time compiling and executing regex.

Comment: Formatting problem; look again

Comment: Won't do -1 but answer is invalid now :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful to you, enter the regular expression and view for yourself:

http://strfriend.com/

The site will depict what a given regular expression will match

Answer (score 1):

It matches an occurrence of `10`, `15`, `20`, `25`, `30`, `35`, `40`, `45`, `50`, `55`, `60`, `65`, `70`, `75`, `80`, or `85` (with a trailing newline character `\n` if one is present).